# Why does a linear term in the gradient violate rotational symmetry?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, field-theory, rotation

I'm reading [David Tong's lecture notes on statistical field theory](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) p.26 and am looking at the derivation of the free for the magnetization field. He notes that we start with terms quadratic in the gradient since a linear term in the gradient would violate the rotational symmetry. Could somebody please give some mathematical justification for why a linear term would violate rotational symmetry?

The free energy is:

$$F[m(\textbf{x})] = \int d^dx [\frac{1}{2} \alpha_2(T)m^2 + \frac{1}{4} \alpha_4(T) m^4 + \frac{1}{2} \gamma(T) (\nabla m)^2 + ... ]\tag{1.28}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a linear term in the gradient. This must be of the following form:
$$ C\int d^d x  \left[ \vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} m \right] , $$
where $\vec{v}$ is some *constant* vector. Now, consider the action of an arbitrary rotation $R$ in $d$-dimensions on the magnetization $\vec{m}$. We then see that $\nabla R\vec{m} = R \nabla \vec{m}$, so
$$ C \int d^d x  \left[ \vec{v} \cdot R \vec{\nabla} m \right] = C \int d^d x \left[ (R^{-1} \vec{v}) \cdot \vec{\nabla} m \right] . $$
Here we have used the fact that $R$ preserves the dot product as $R \vec{a} \cdot R \vec{b} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$. Since in general $R^{-1} \vec{v} \neq \vec{v}$ for nonzero $\vec{v}$, we therefore notice that the action of $R$ does not leave the linear term fixed in general if $\vec{v}$ is nonzero.